# Unexpected behaviour from AutoCompleteTextView.onItemClick in landscape mode

Tags: android

I have an adapter populated with 100 strings connected to a AutoCompleteTextView. In portrait mode this works as I expect it to, if I type in "11" all 100 elements show up as a dropdown list and the correct index is passed as the index parameter in onItemClick.

I don't understand what happens in landscape mode though, if I type in "11" only the first 20 elements show up in the list and only the first 4 elements in the list pass the correct index when I click on them in the onItemClick method. When I click on other list elements the index is -1? Also I can see the count is 100 in landscape mode so why are only the first 20 showing?

Anyone know why this is?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        adapter.add(new String("11" + i));
    }

    AutoCompleteTextView ac = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search_auto_complete);

    ac.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Index: " + index);
            Log.d(TAG, "Elements in adapter: " + adapterView.getCount());               

            if(index == -1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Index not found, aborting AutoCompleteTextView.onItemClick!");
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    ac.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_auto_complete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems this only occurs on Samsung Galaxy SII and SIII running Android 4+. I didn't have the same problem on a Galaxy SII running an older Android version. Still, if anyone has run into this problem before I would appreciate it if they could share a solution/workaround for this.